# How to check if variable was set inside htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I have this code in my htaccess running on apache 2.4

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ".*" DOCACHE=YES

<If "%{ENV:DOCACHE} == 'YES'">

    Header set CUSTOMCACHE "CUSTOM CACHE VALUE"

</If>
```

But it never works, I mean, the variable "DOCACHE" should be created for every request and becuse of that the CUSTOMCACHE header should be also created but it never gets created. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Should be similar to your other question. Use the `reqenv('DOCACHE')` to check

Comment: @PanamaJack the problem is that apache does not see the variable set with REWRITERULE when using <if>. Do you know the reason?